# Internet Explorer and other software crash on exit

Tags: windows-7

On a fresh installation of Windows 7 x64, Internet Explorer keeps crashing on every exit. This happens with IE 11, but I tried to downgrade it to IE 9, but the problem pertsists. Starting IE without plugins also does not help.

The same happens with some other programs, for example, Adobe Acrobat Reader.

What should I do to fix?

Comment: Does it work OK with a different user profile?  I've seen similar and the fix was to delete the user profile and start a new one, so just curious.

Comment: @TheCleaner no. I have changed the profile because of another problem, but this problem is still there. Also starting IE without plugins does not help.

Comment: Do you get errors in the application log?  If so, what are they (edit your OP with them)?

Comment: @TheCleaner where it is?

Comment: eventvwr (event viewer in Windows), check the Application log immediately after IE crashes and closes.

Comment: @TheCleaner  it says the problem module is kbHook.dll_unloaded

Comment: @TheCleane The file seemingly is located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite\kbhook.dll

Comment: @Anixx - Try and uninstall `Bluetooth Suite`

Answer (score 2):

IF kbhook.dll is the issue and is found where you stated in comments: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite\kbhook.dll` I would recommend the following:

1. If you aren't using bluetooth at all, look at disabling any startup items that refer to bluetooth by running `msconfig` and looking at the startup items carefully.  You could also look in `Programs and Features` and look at uninstalling "Bluetooth Suite".
2. Try running `sfc /scannow` from an administrative command prompt.

If those don't fix the issue, then you'll need to update your OP with further details that really explain what errors you are getting at that point.

Comment: is there a way to just disable this error screen?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is.  You could try switching to another browser like FF or Chrome and see if it errors on exit.  If not, and you don't care to fix the issue, that might be a solution for you.

Comment: there is no error in ff

Comment: If you don't need bluetooth, just disable it then.  In `services` look for ones that start with `bluetooth` and stop them.  Then check IE and see if you still get the error.  If not, then disable the services.  Again, this is if you don't need bluetooth.